# Combining two date frames into the same columns but under different dates

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames with the same column names, but the dates for each is different, like so:

```
#df1
      Date      col1    col2   col3
1  2017-07-10    1       2      3
2  2017-07-17    4       5      6
3  2017-07-24    7       8      9

#df2
      Date      col1    col2   col3
1  2017-07-11    10      11     12
2  2017-07-18    13      14     15
3  2017-07-25    16      17     18
```

I want to merge the two to get a single data frame with the same columns, 
but retaining information to the corresponding dates and ordered by ascending date like so:

```
#desired result
      Date      col1    col2   col3
1  2017-07-10    1       2      3
2  2017-07-11   10      11     12
3  2017-07-17    4       5      6
4  2017-07-18   13      14     15
5  2017-07-24    7       8      9
6  2017-07-25   16      17     18
```

The closest I got to it was using `merge(df1, df2, by = "Date", all = TRUE)`, but this gave me:

```
     Date      col1    col2   col3   col1    col2   col3
1  2017-07-10    1       2      3     NA      NA     NA
2  2017-07-11   NA      NA     NA     10      11     12
3  2017-07-17    4       5      6     NA      NA     NA
4  2017-07-18   NA      NA     NA     13      14     15
5  2017-07-24    7       8      9     NA      NA     NA
6  2017-07-25   NA      NA     NA     16      17     18
```

EDIT: So trying `rbind` gives me an error, revealing that I have some time series date in my dataframes and preventing me from obtaining the desired merging of the data frames. Here's the output when I do `str(df1)` and `str(df2)` for the actual dataframes I'm using:

```
str(df1)
data.frame':   14 obs. of  4 variables:
$ Date: Date, format: "2017-07-10" "2017-07-17" "2017-07-24" "2017-07-31" 
...
$ bal : Time-Series  from 128 to 141: 12448736 12557277 12549660 12517634 
12480479 ...
$ 80  : Time-Series  from 128 to 141: 14825217 15032135 15047306 15029003 
15003920 ...
$ 95  : Time-Series  from 128 to 141: 16083250 16342246 16369480 16358442 
16339749 ...

str(df2)
'data.frame':   14 obs. of  4 variables:
$ Date: Date, format: "2017-07-04" "2017-07-11" "2017-07-18" "2017-07-25" 
...
$ bal : Time-Series  from 143 to 156: 6059787 6059787 6059787 6059787 
6059787 ...
$ 80  : Time-Series  from 143 to 156: 11234537 11239924 11245305 11250681 
11256051 ...
$ 95  : Time-Series  from 143 to 156: 1.4e+07 1.4e+07 1.4e+07 1.4e+07 
1.4e+07 ...
```

Comment: use `rbind` instead of `merge`

Comment: Perhaps you could try `dplyr::bind_rows` or `rbind` in Base R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

union_all(df1, df2) %>%
  arrange(date)
```

Comment: This does it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As your two dataframes contain different dates, you can simply combine them with `rbind` into a new dataframe and order it according to the Date column.
Given that your dataframes contain timeseries (`ts`) objects, you first have to convert these to numeric before doing the `rbind`.

```
df1 = data.frame(df1[1],apply(df1[-1],2,as.numeric))
df2 = data.frame(df2[1],apply(df2[-1],2,as.numeric))
df = rbind(df1,df2)
df = df[order(df$Date),]
        Date col1 col2 col3
1 2017-07-10    1    2    3
4 2017-07-11   10   11   12
2 2017-07-17    4    5    6
5 2017-07-18   13   14   15
3 2017-07-24    7    8    9
6 2017-07-25   16   17   18
```

Comment: When I used `rbind` for the actual df I'm working with, I get `Error in `[<-.ts`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(6059786.87467336, 6059786.87467336,  : 
  only replacement of elements is allowed`. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Do your dataframes contain a time series (ts) object? Check str(df1) and str(df2).

Comment: Looks like it. For df1,it says it contains time series values from 128 to 141 and for df2, it says time-series from 143 to 156.

Comment: Could you post the result of str(df1) and str(df2)?

Comment: If you don't care about keeping the ts format, you can do `df1=data.frame(df1[1],apply(df1[-1],2,as.numeric))` and `df2=data.frame(df2[1],apply(df2[-1],2,as.numeric))`, before doing the `rbind`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table` after placing the datasets in a `list`.  Here, the `mget` returns the value of the objects in a `list` and then `order` by 'Date'

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mget(paste0('df', 1:2)))[order(Date)]
#         Date col1 col2 col3
#1: 2017-07-10    1    2    3
#2: 2017-07-11   10   11   12
#3: 2017-07-17    4    5    6
#4: 2017-07-18   13   14   15
#5: 2017-07-24    7    8    9
#6: 2017-07-25   16   17   18
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `bind_rows` and `arrange` from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  arrange(Date)
```